# Linux kernel's vm_offset in anonymous mapping

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mmap

Is there a purpose for vm_pgoff in an "anonymous" mapping (vm_area_struct) in Linux kernel?

For file mapping it's obvious, but in an anonymous mapping, it seems that it's just `vm_start >> PAGE_SHIFT` in all cases. Is that really true? Can someone explain or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `vm_pgoff`. It is probably set to `vm_start >> PAGE_SHIFT` to make the kernel code more convenient.

Comment: It seems that way, but the thing I am dealing with is that this causes problems when the mapping is moved (remapped using `mremap`). Offsets don't match and mappings can't be merged, which causes unnecessary fragmentation, especially if `vm_pgoff` is not used for anonymous mappings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

from the linux man page:

> **MAP_ANONYMOUS**
> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to  zero.   The
> fd  argument  is  ignored;  however,  some  implementations  require fd to be -1 if
> MAP_ANONYMOUS (or MAP_ANON) is specified, and portable applications  should  ensure
> this.  The offset argument should be zero.  The use of MAP_ANONYMOUS in conjunction
> with MAP_SHARED is supported on Linux only since kernel 2.4.

so for an anonymous mapping, it should always be 0.

Comment: Yes, that's true for a mmap call, but inside the kernel in vm_area_struct there is vm_offset which is as far as I know always vm_start >> PAGE_SHIFT, hence the question, if that's always so.